# How to send a message to a channel of MS Team using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

How to send a message to a channel of MS Team using Graph APÌ?

I have used below commands to generate token for grant_type client_credentials.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' --data-urlencode 'client_id={client_id}' --data-urlencode 'client_secret={client_secret}' --data-urlencode 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
```

Then using token generated i ran following curl command to get list of channels and it run successfully.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team_ID}/channels/' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IjBMa0VQY1V4RjgxWnJOTnlUb2Z1SUFRc2VEVUYwQ25wa3pPcWFiY2wwcjgiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCIsImtpZCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2dyYXBoLm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb20iLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3N0cy53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC9lODZiZjgyMS1kNmVhLTQ1MTAtOGZmYi03YzY4NmM2NDU3ZjIvIiwiaWF0IjoxNjA1MzU1NDg5LCJuYmYiOjE2MDUzNTU0ODksImV4cCI6MTYwNTM1OTM4OSwiYWlvIjoiRTJSZ1lPQzZ2dWFYN3Awc2s3WmM0Ym1uNjZjd0FnQT0iLCJhcHBfZGlzcGxheW5hbWUiOiJmeHRlc3QiLCJhcHBpZCI6ImVmYWQzZjlhLWY4MmQtNGNkMS05OTE1LTIwNDA0YjQ2NmYzNyIsImFwcGlkYWNyIjoiMSIsImlkcCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc3RzLndpbmRvd3MubmV0L2U4NmJmODIxLWQ2ZWEtNDUxMC04ZmZiLTdjNjg2YzY0NTdmMi8iLCJpZHR5cCI6ImFwcCIsIm9pZCI6Ijc2ZmQwM2FlLTE3MDEtNGFiZS1iMmI2LWIwNGVmZWRhYWU4NSIsInJoIjoiMC5BQUFBSWZocjZPcldFRVdQLTN4b2JHUlg4cG9fcmU4dC1ORk1tUlVnUUV0R2J6ZFRBQUEuIiwicm9sZXMiOlsiVGVhbVNldHRpbmdzLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJUZWFtTWVtYmVyLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiUGxhY2UuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJDaGF0LlVwZGF0ZVBvbGljeVZpb2xhdGlvbi5BbGwiLCJJZGVudGl0eVVzZXJGbG93LlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJTY2hlZHVsZS5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiUG9saWN5LlJlYWQuQ29uZGl0aW9uYWxBY2Nlc3MiLCJUZWFtc0FwcEluc3RhbGxhdGlvbi5SZWFkRm9yVXNlci5BbGwiLCJVc2VyU2hpZnRQcmVmZXJlbmNlcy5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIlRlYW13b3JrLk1pZ3JhdGUuQWxsIiwiQ2FsbHMuSm9pbkdyb3VwQ2FsbC5BbGwiLCJFZHVSb3N0ZXIuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJQb2xpY3kuUmVhZFdyaXRlLlBlcm1pc3Npb25HcmFudCIsIkRldmljZU1hbmFnZW1lbnRNYW5hZ2VkRGV2aWNlcy5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIk9ubGluZU1lZXRpbmdzLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiQWNjZXNzUmV2aWV3LlJlYWRXcml0ZS5NZW1iZXJzaGlwIiwiRGV2aWNlLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiUG9saWN5LlJlYWRXcml0ZS5Db25kaXRpb25hbEFjY2VzcyIsIkJpdGxvY2tlcktleS5SZWFkQmFzaWMuQWxsIiwiVGVhbXNUYWIuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJQb2xpY3kuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uTWV0aG9kIiwiQXBwcm92YWxSZXF1ZXN0LlJlYWRXcml0ZS5DdXN0b21lckxvY2tib3giLCJVc2VyQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25NZXRob2QuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJUZWFtc0FjdGl2aXR5LlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiQml0bG9ja2VyS2V5LlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiVGVhbXNBcHAuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJUZWFtTWVtYmVyLlJlYWRXcml0ZU5vbk93bmVyUm9sZS5BbGwiLCJNYWlsLlJlYWRXcml0ZSIsIlByaW50ZXIuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJJZGVudGl0eVJpc2tFdmVudC5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiT3JnQ29udGFjdC5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIlRlYW1zQXBwSW5zdGFsbGF0aW9uLlJlYWRGb3JDaGF0LkFsbCIsIk9ubGluZU1lZXRpbmdzLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJEZXZpY2UuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIlBvbGljeS5SZWFkLlBlcm1pc3Npb25HcmFudCIsIkNoYW5uZWwuRGVsZXRlLkFsbCIsIlVzZXIuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIlBvbGljeS5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25GbG93cyIsIkRvbWFpbi5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiQXBwbGljYXRpb24uUmVhZFdyaXRlLk93bmVkQnkiLCJQcmludGVyLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJTZWN1cml0eUFjdGlvbnMuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIkNoYW5uZWxTZXR0aW5ncy5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIlNlY3VyaXR5RXZlbnRzLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiVGVhbXNUYWIuQ3JlYXRlIiwiVXNlckF1dGhlbnRpY2F0aW9uTWV0aG9kLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJEZWxlZ2F0ZWRQZXJtaXNzaW9uR3JhbnQuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIkNhbGVuZGFycy5SZWFkIiwiTWFpbC5SZWFkQmFzaWMuQWxsIiwiUHJpdmlsZWdlZEFjY2Vzcy5SZWFkLkF6dXJlQUQiLCJQcmludEpvYi5NYW5hZ2UuQWxsIiwiUm9sZU1hbmFnZW1lbnQuUmVhZC5EaXJlY3RvcnkiLCJQb2xpY3kuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uQ29uZmlndXJhdGlvbiIsIkVkdUFzc2lnbm1lbnRzLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJDaGFubmVsLlJlYWRCYXNpYy5BbGwiLCJTaG9ydE5vdGVzLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJQZW9wbGUuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJUZWFtc0FwcEluc3RhbGxhdGlvbi5SZWFkV3JpdGVTZWxmRm9yVXNlci5BbGwiLCJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbi5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiQ2FsbHMuSW5pdGlhdGVHcm91cENhbGwuQWxsIiwiR3JvdXAuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJBZG1pbmlzdHJhdGl2ZVVuaXQuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJQcmludEpvYi5SZWFkV3JpdGVCYXNpYy5BbGwiLCJUZWFtc0FwcEluc3RhbGxhdGlvbi5SZWFkV3JpdGVTZWxmRm9yQ2hhdC5BbGwiLCJBY2Nlc3NSZXZpZXcuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIk9uUHJlbWlzZXNQdWJsaXNoaW5nUHJvZmlsZXMuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIkRpcmVjdG9yeS5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiVGVhbXNBY3Rpdml0eS5TZW5kIiwiVGVhbXNUYWIuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIklkZW50aXR5Umlza3lVc2VyLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJFZHVBc3NpZ25tZW50cy5SZWFkV3JpdGVCYXNpYy5BbGwiLCJNYWlsYm94U2V0dGluZ3MuUmVhZCIsIkVkdUFkbWluaXN0cmF0aW9uLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiQ2FsbHMuSm9pbkdyb3VwQ2FsbEFzR3Vlc3QuQWxsIiwiVGhyZWF0SW5kaWNhdG9ycy5SZWFkV3JpdGUuT3duZWRCeSIsIlRlYW1zQXBwSW5zdGFsbGF0aW9uLlJlYWRXcml0ZVNlbGZGb3JUZWFtLkFsbCIsIlNpdGVzLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiUHJpbnRKb2IuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJEZXZpY2VNYW5hZ2VtZW50U2VydmljZUNvbmZpZy5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIlNpdGVzLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJTZXJ2aWNlTWVzc2FnZS5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIkNvbnRhY3RzLlJlYWRXcml0ZSIsIlRlYW0uQ3JlYXRlIiwiQXBwcm92YWxSZXF1ZXN0LlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BZG1pbkNvbnNlbnRSZXF1ZXN0IiwiR3JvdXAuQ3JlYXRlIiwiR3JvdXAuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIlRlYW1zQXBwLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJTaXRlcy5NYW5hZ2UuQWxsIiwiU2VjdXJpdHlFdmVudHMuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIk5vdGVzLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiUHJpbnRKb2IuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIkVudGl0bGVtZW50TWFuYWdlbWVudC5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIkNhbGxSZWNvcmRzLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiSWRlbnRpdHlVc2VyRmxvdy5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIlVzZXIuSW52aXRlLkFsbCIsIkNoYXRNZXNzYWdlLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiRWR1Um9zdGVyLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJGaWxlcy5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiRGlyZWN0b3J5LlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiUm9sZU1hbmFnZW1lbnQuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJDYWxsUmVjb3JkLVBzdG5DYWxscy5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIlByaXZpbGVnZWRBY2Nlc3MuUmVhZC5BenVyZVJlc291cmNlcyIsIlVzZXIuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJBcHByb3ZhbFJlcXVlc3QuUmVhZC5BZG1pbkNvbnNlbnRSZXF1ZXN0IiwiRG9tYWluLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiRWR1QXNzaWdubWVudHMuUmVhZEJhc2ljLkFsbCIsIkVkdVJvc3Rlci5SZWFkQmFzaWMuQWxsIiwiQ2hhbm5lbE1lbWJlci5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIlNjaGVkdWxlLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiVGVhbXNBcHBJbnN0YWxsYXRpb24uUmVhZFdyaXRlRm9yVXNlci5BbGwiLCJEZXZpY2VNYW5hZ2VtZW50U2VydmljZUNvbmZpZy5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiVXNlck5vdGlmaWNhdGlvbi5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQ3JlYXRlZEJ5QXBwIiwiR3JvdXBNZW1iZXIuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJUZWFtTWVtYmVyLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJBcHByb3ZhbFJlcXVlc3QuUmVhZC5DdXN0b21lckxvY2tib3giLCJVc2VyU2hpZnRQcmVmZXJlbmNlcy5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiRGV2aWNlTWFuYWdlbWVudFJCQUMuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJUcnVzdEZyYW1ld29ya0tleVNldC5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiSWRlbnRpdHlQcm92aWRlci5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiRmlsZXMuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJFbnRpdGxlbWVudE1hbmFnZW1lbnQuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbi5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiRGV2aWNlTWFuYWdlbWVudENvbmZpZ3VyYXRpb24uUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJUZWFtLlJlYWRCYXNpYy5BbGwiLCJQcmludFRhc2tEZWZpbml0aW9uLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJNYWlsLlJlYWQiLCJBcHBSb2xlQXNzaWdubWVudC5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiQ2hhdC5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIkRldmljZU1hbmFnZW1lbnRNYW5hZ2VkRGV2aWNlcy5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiQ2hhbm5lbE1lc3NhZ2UuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJQcml2aWxlZ2VkQWNjZXNzLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BenVyZUFEIiwiVXNlci5FeHBvcnQuQWxsIiwiRWR1QXNzaWdubWVudHMuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJTZWN1cml0eUFjdGlvbnMuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJUZWFtc0FwcEluc3RhbGxhdGlvbi5SZWFkV3JpdGVGb3JUZWFtLkFsbCIsIlRocmVhdEFzc2Vzc21lbnQuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJJZGVudGl0eVByb3ZpZGVyLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiUHJpdmlsZWdlZEFjY2Vzcy5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQXp1cmVSZXNvdXJjZXMiLCJUZWFtU2V0dGluZ3MuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJDYWxlbmRhcnMuUmVhZFdyaXRlIiwiSWRlbnRpdHlSaXNreVVzZXIuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJBY2Nlc3NSZXZpZXcuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJUZXJtU3RvcmUuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJFZHVBZG1pbmlzdHJhdGlvbi5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiTWFpbC5TZW5kIiwiQXBwcm92YWxSZXF1ZXN0LlJlYWRXcml0ZS5Qcml2aWxpZ2VkQWNjZXNzIiwiUHJpdmlsZWdlZEFjY2Vzcy5SZWFkLkF6dXJlQURHcm91cCIsIkNoYXQuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIkFwcHJvdmFsUmVxdWVzdC5SZWFkV3JpdGUuRW50aXRsZW1lbnRNYW5hZ2VtZW50IiwiVXNlci5NYW5hZ2VJZGVudGl0aWVzLkFsbCIsIkluZm9ybWF0aW9uUHJvdGVjdGlvblBvbGljeS5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIkNoYW5uZWxNZXNzYWdlLlVwZGF0ZVBvbGljeVZpb2xhdGlvbi5BbGwiLCJNYWlsYm94U2V0dGluZ3MuUmVhZFdyaXRlIiwiT3JnYW5pemF0aW9uLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiQ2hhbm5lbE1lbWJlci5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiUm9sZU1hbmFnZW1lbnQuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkRpcmVjdG9yeSIsIkdyb3VwTWVtYmVyLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJDb250YWN0cy5SZWFkIiwiSWRlbnRpdHlSaXNrRXZlbnQuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJNYWlsLlJlYWRCYXNpYyIsIkNoYW5uZWxTZXR0aW5ncy5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiQWRtaW5pc3RyYXRpdmVVbml0LlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJBdWRpdExvZy5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIkNoYW5uZWwuQ3JlYXRlIiwiUG9saWN5LlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiVGVybVN0b3JlLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJBcHByb3ZhbFJlcXVlc3QuUmVhZC5Qcml2aWxpZ2VkQWNjZXNzIiwiTWVtYmVyLlJlYWQuSGlkZGVuIiwiRGV2aWNlTWFuYWdlbWVudENvbmZpZ3VyYXRpb24uUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIkNoYXQuUmVhZEJhc2ljLkFsbCIsIkNhbGxzLkFjY2Vzc01lZGlhLkFsbCIsIkFwcGxpY2F0aW9uLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiUHJvZ3JhbUNvbnRyb2wuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJEZXZpY2VNYW5hZ2VtZW50TWFuYWdlZERldmljZXMuUHJpdmlsZWdlZE9wZXJhdGlvbnMuQWxsIiwiU2VydmljZUhlYWx0aC5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIlRlYW1zQXBwSW5zdGFsbGF0aW9uLlJlYWRXcml0ZUZvckNoYXQuQWxsIiwiU2l0ZXMuRnVsbENvbnRyb2wuQWxsIiwiUG9saWN5LlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BdXRob3JpemF0aW9uIiwiRGV2aWNlTWFuYWdlbWVudEFwcHMuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIkRldmljZU1hbmFnZW1lbnRBcHBzLlJlYWQuQWxsIiwiVGhyZWF0SW5kaWNhdG9ycy5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIlRlYW1zQXBwSW5zdGFsbGF0aW9uLlJlYWRGb3JUZWFtLkFsbCIsIlNob3J0Tm90ZXMuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJQcm9ncmFtQ29udHJvbC5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiUmVwb3J0cy5SZWFkLkFsbCIsIlByaW50Sm9iLlJlYWRCYXNpYy5BbGwiLCJDYWxscy5Jbml0aWF0ZS5BbGwiLCJFeHRlcm5hbEl0ZW0uUmVhZFdyaXRlLkFsbCIsIk5vdGVzLlJlYWRXcml0ZS5BbGwiLCJBcHByb3ZhbFJlcXVlc3QuUmVhZC5FbnRpdGxlbWVudE1hbmFnZW1lbnQiLCJEZXZpY2VNYW5hZ2VtZW50UkJBQy5SZWFkV3JpdGUuQWxsIiwiVHJ1c3RGcmFtZXdvcmtLZXlTZXQuUmVhZC5BbGwiLCJQb2xpY3kuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkZlYXR1cmVSb2xsb3V0IiwiUG9saWN5LlJlYWRXcml0ZS5UcnVzdEZyYW1ld29yayIsIlByaXZpbGVnZWRBY2Nlc3MuUmVhZFdyaXRlLkF6dXJlQURHcm91cCJdLCJzdWIiOiI3NmZkMDNhZS0xNzAxLTRhYmUtYjJiNi1iMDRlZmVkYWFlODUiLCJ0ZW5hbnRfcmVnaW9uX3Njb3BlIjoiQVMiLCJ0aWQiOiJlODZiZjgyMS1kNmVhLTQ1MTAtOGZmYi03YzY4NmM2NDU3ZjIiLCJ1dGkiOiJUUHo5bkNvNU8wU2o2R2FYaDZvWEFBIiwidmVyIjoiMS4wIiwieG1zX3RjZHQiOjE1OTQ2MjgyNTZ9.NyL_Pf26Xq7ciHP241A8hSxqj2pqgLJSGfGngBdauAmHeFCbxxPQJPGN1OgyFqn_RS5flIgFAtqDU7bEJhuVemYWhngi2Yj-Yu3FCptFwWhpIHp03IeChbjX1CVIR1ESHuCFiH_EQSXAdk9spPB8iW8Yzp5q2gwVwWhxQgbdixXZ-lzT6f6TTBCQqkPkazMFwUxEHQtDXEQfYjdNu5V3W4in1PM5I4EKdo_tw7H4qMG4aImCGtVnX4P_jVEHPkk_8888glqPLmABpd7P6PGxnyirSFox60UFYT2ISe2Xqh5MwE0fGUyEKc_-0MHubmVfm6qbnz_TiZAYqiteZVwmSg'
```

Below is the response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#teams('e76f9b0b')/channels",
    "@odata.count": 3,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "19:d893c@thread.tacv2",
            "displayName": "General",
            "description": null,
            "isFavoriteByDefault": null,
            "email": "",
            "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%3a%40thread.tacv2/General?groupId=e76f9b0b-b6d3&tenantId=e86bf",
            "membershipType": "standard"
        },
        {
            "id": "19:44e0b@thread.tacv2",
            "displayName": "apiSec-Issues",
            "description": null,
            "isFavoriteByDefault": null,
            "email": "",
            "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%3b0b%40thread.tacv2/apiSec-Issues?groupId=e76f9b0b-b6d3&tenantId=e86bf821-d6ea-4510",
            "membershipType": "standard"
        },
        {
            "id": "19:721251965a30@thread.tacv2",
            "displayName": "Dev",
            "description": "This channel is where we debate all future development plans",
            "isFavoriteByDefault": null,
            "email": "",
            "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%330%40thread.tacv2/Dev?groupId=e76f9b0b-b6d3-42bb-baf1-6a798e4&tenantId=e86bf821-d6ea-4510-8ffb-7c686c64",
            "membershipType": "standard"
        }
    ]
}
```

However it throws unauthorized error when tried to post/sent a message to a channel using token  generated from above mention curl command

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team_ID}/channels/{channel_ID}/messages/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IlRiYnhpOWlNZWZaTUZOaDNhNERIVDdlakNheU5QR1V2X3RhYzdwM3hxMVEiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCIsImtpZCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCJ9.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.a2gPsNyiJxNn3gD1WgibPuD55VC1hxirBkHjMa5xIn242AJJ2bpITcuun3glSSel9rHefmVEnqV9UXkSeq4OJTMGL-XrzZSUw09EkbKxOIq9FqWIJLe_LZS54to6xM62z4V-3YrNSHS9dUsQXRRoaeTe6_n_zzdx_epFtvoNiKnxmSggMN1Ly8yBJPitDpZsqjLtIRWcLRnARFD-_A8VkBjGr2k4KWTlcFlt7ltPDRfqEio7FNpRq4-B_4M14JuDEPAybdoJKXoyg87bFUmNMFf-lPnEmxNuHcUmYU3iy8ZJnX6SU1vCZwln0dQMUb_U7sOI796af7g8INksxVAwCA' \
--data-raw '{
  "body": {
    "content": "Hello World"
  }
}'
```

In response it throws Unauthorized Error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Unauthorized",
        "message": "Unauthorized",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-14T12:54:36",
            "request-id": "d2e6aaa7-2884-4e4d-bd71-b92038b",
            "client-request-id": "d2e6aaa7-2884-4e4d-bd71"
        }
    }
}
```

Just to get this working for testing purpose, i have given all permissions for delegated and application(About 442 permissions) with admin consent but still  response throws "Unauthorized Error"

So can someone help out over here, where am i getting it wrong.

What is right procedure to send a message to channel of a MS team using MS-Graph-api or what else needs to be enable/done which i am forgetting over here, to get this working.

Comment: Only delegated permission will work in this scenario & not the application permissions. Make sure you have the following permissions - ChannelMessage.Send, Group.ReadWrite.All - as one of the permissions is required to call this API. Just to isolate the above issue, test the same Graph API call, with the above said permissions in Microsoft Graph explorer and see if you can able to send message to channel or not. Here's the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: I checked the above error log info, but it doesnt have any info for analysis. Still if you can repro the issue, then get us the latest requestid, timestamp for further analysis.

Comment: Yes these "  ChannelMessage.Send, Group.ReadWrite.All " permissions are also enable/provided. Here's latest Error log ``` {
    "error": {
        "code": "Unauthorized",
        "message": "Unauthorized",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-15T02:19:41",
            "request-id": "ecccba94-b8ce-40d5-b9ff-5fd399ffe4c5",
            "client-request-id": "ecccba94-b8ce-40d5-b9ff-5fd399ffe4c5"
        }
    }
}  ```. I got above response when run from terminal and from postman

Comment: When tried to same command from Graph-Explorer having following " ChannelMessage.Send, Group.ReadWrite.All " mention permissions for delegated . Strangely it throws below response                                   {
    "error": {
        "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
        "message": "Method not allowed.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-15T02:38:17",
            "request-id": "4448eed4-881a-4fad-98e1-bacf23ebb178",
            "client-request-id": "f18c5ddd-140e-3624-0de8-9b5ffd928ab5"
        }
    }
} with auto-generated token for sign-in user in Graph-Explor

Comment: When run same request from Graph-Explorer also including bearer token in  header generated for grant_type client_credentials from postman, i got below response                  {
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-15T02:53:22",
            "request-id": "c664d16f-2754-4ee3-b355-eb0eba066bcf",
            "client-request-id": "e4707e65-3d05-f7c0-2b97-8dae57a4cb88"
        }
    }
}. What else could i try to get desired results.

Comment: (1) The first call is telling that you're not authorized to perform the action/API call.  (2) Second error is telling that the entity set that you used with POST call is not supported (3) As i said earlier, the call is only supported in delegated permission only, but you tried with client credential grant flow - which is not supported; thats why you got the error.

Comment: Yes, you were right using client_credentials grant flow does not works for delegated permissions for sending messages as suggested on this link https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/30daysmsgraph-day-12-authentication-and-authorization-scenarios/ and i have used grant_type as authorization code to send messages to a channel successfully

Comment: Wonderful update. Glad to help @devops-admin!!

Comment: I will move this to answer. Please upvote it. So it can be useful to others as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Only delegated permission will work in this scenario & not the application permissions. Make sure you have the following permissions - ChannelMessage.Send, Group.ReadWrite.All - as one of the permissions is required to call this API.
- Just to isolate the above issue, test the same Graph API call, with
  the above said permissions in Microsoft Graph explorer and see if you
  can able to send message to channel or not. Here's the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).
- Based [on that you used grant_type](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/30daysmsgraph-day-12-authentication-and-authorization-scenarios/) as authorization code to send messages to a channel successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Use grant_type as authorization code for sending messages to a channel as grant_type client_credentials is not supported in delegated permission as pointed out on this link as well https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/30daysmsgraph-day-12-authentication-and-authorization-scenarios/

For others to move forward follow above link to get the authorization code and use it to generate bearer access token  to send messages to a channel

Delegated permissions required to generate bearer access token: "openid profile User.Read email"

To Generate access-token

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; stsservicecookie=ests; fpc=AiMjowz5Jo5EvQyTMhzOqaQ9npEsAQAAAOMFRtcOAAAAqSBP-gEAAABXBkbXDgAAAA' --data-urlencode 'client_id=<client_ID>' --data-urlencode 'client_secret=<client_secret>' --data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=http://localhost' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' --data-urlencode 'scope=openid profile offline_access User.Read' --data-urlencode 'code=0.AAAAIfhr6OrWEEWP-3xobGRX8hpZv2PH4fVJh6PLsdEHaztTAOY.AQABAAIAAAB2UyzwtQEKR7-rWbgdcBZIMB3WJhW2dvCBgjVNf-tzDc_9Yc7YnN1JrIZtaE8b0L4RylYkzJkGWZAcxeTrMDhhjrjCJDGMOjkLPf8Jd0lLX6C7tFOU-RRg1tNDds0kI1RDdRJRYBMVFOr_riKgCwAKWgKrAd18Tr-anqLt_iTn7TLmCIN1dsL4wVFJPkhOBS0yPaoz0B07CzHWX2dUxMKhVoe7DpPibRxa6cue4zpm0JNqRWfuENIBf5qtOdghIeTa4DvrIosjhEKswdIKD1bc4LQIt6-y7-fUn7pNgbJH1b2PfOu-rtrrBjCgra9MMcnWKT_rx7Rgi_VHxERmm06SubWNI_YmmAwaSqj8ni_qUFZNULr5IT0RPIdaFmnb7xduvwfaeBdho0cHGJoBR3omYsaHygEK-xraP9vD-Dm3NdqlVYuQYKB2O5uVuyTDA--7sN7Ay5gQHkz98xfOuT4aU18YQ1Ji1vE5KffCbsFoUwzHiLoz-QcdMs7BBHR0C13z1o_qjx8SYgWZhlOwzA4-r91ErOi-AoZYqgk6yBhP_w7K-3YNFcxkNaqi4LIg8rarP0bFeioJgW3Htmsd1Ogk0y5kUSUnu1o5-paac8J9p9gpxuxM_Bj3GJ8P-SkuPueNY16kQ_qlW-JuqtrRp0mtFyeNVpHDY2vCUbJRpCw85tX247A-iGYBlsE7_BEj2wqcbeIZwXLOoKSmwxP2I5i_69m07FOz3hmYcl39sAjq8SItfFWcMPW1fWTEzqJy9dGsYulGHEDtx2iMTJsf9X_SEUrnAO8bqNLbJFDVcTFoxFrqFB7VjrjWH-4ed8erdHiEJnGVVjuQ1a_aW7pLIdo0r5zvF4PA9cvVjAlFyLi0ybhWD1vKu-EeTDqyG4uO2NW45Jow5GDGVPYIr2fKNZWdzNzFgcMsqo5hCsobL9lvd7DQIsa4W2dZ9UJjMQZ5NGKdcnL6ks8ZX44_DBcTkRBkWIXSJqEIh0WxdHjvC-_hWBifJ4xArQ5aAl5TucxEv7wwpB-tGou2mG_XvyLxNnrbOt-ltyc5aZTRZ1J_iOO7wX8AkNXM4-MsSFESyPAGhgJlClZCEtOZZLKhe99vmTvpinWyS72T5E1yWOUSCopFr2X2e0g-Fi8q1pNdAk1tw91ZtGhPBXk8BJAzjUut1T8nHiG_OE4inmGaK7rGsy-uKtCQGuALjxgpi_kAtDfGhYyzxiPe7Itu1od31M83y6H7ZOC9XVkQrI9jrt_Jn3wTwqRjFuwWwpCxK2iAc6y3pskgAA'
```

Below will be the response

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "ChannelMessage.Send Group.ReadWrite.All openid profile User.Read email",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IloxNG9xVEI5cjFYcldGZUJQQzNjU0VwR2p3aXlpUUZPVC1hTXBsaTZrMFkiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCIsImtpZCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCJ9.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.SDn4NIiHLxvGp0odn7C_hXZ0juSsgnyE_Dc0uTwMK_jP_n7-SjisYfw1vOoX7st5-C27_HwLoSWxUt1cqL7ENcrt_7HXvZSwFsXVN4JCeEOVZUZUzUakcmttUISPPPygLhv4-EPD-sBC8TDs9ncIYDUKqbTYh1aKkRsIK5O19GvoJQ4UUzHV6o-raW8jTBdXRfH1Bz6N7CPfcPkivTn1a-zOthy1HrlFBCFCErJBum_3QhmAHkoA9UPOEKKZeJBl_k3VqsZBcNById-X591ukyi06Kk8kHfYoigiiXm7lv0-NLsHoVq9e4sBemIjYzHd3mUhN3ayPYOTAwnUCsb9kA",
    "refresh_token": "0.AAAAIfhr6OrWEEWP-3xobGRX8hpZv2PH4fVJh6PLsdEHaztTAOY.AgABAAAAAAB2UyzwtQEKR7-rWbgdcBZIAQDs_wIA9P-VaK7kTxu67GVpgkENaxo5RaJz1G_GtnJ7x9V-YNDrLpkidtc-D_zgeGu8FpyC_Zh0ZwFZ_4orR_2q3mFf_J2MJ8caI6qrsyIDRPhRZE9PWZ1fYTfIlB4zbIg5l2B2_M5u7FsBdAjvkCelDNlG36Ev9vFBGSHG1XY4sJwVTmyTrgp_dyafCfc4-JqbQwUqIp44MdZon2n5XhfeOJsFDWPcx0VyPwL4yTLZ78htAv41msxO16qnOihaRESza1gpRAlcYvTbFMJyJBPQny-WOqIuGtJ8tRbbj8GkeSmV4IJ0-jkeHhCUD3JQVcyR9vepmKLGoH1ACVnm47_qYMKli4dR8MiOFReAbm1uP3YmGDDN9enRoIBCHz3w0GQYjb9RVDE9hZuzlP6jSx34GXcEOboXe6MbQpxO-Tg70BFk9jP8U7OMlht8WYFBm_ztGkBuDAvMe2dAtJjOI1VbqYQhuJ-h_iWco3jh9pexDQkaIG_L1v8ByAvCJ3dxbkMceC1Vgq7ekmRwanWL2GqPYfpmYF40U1VG30QhhjWdA4lx_QkpvqqHMU8D3heS1NsBtIdJ4XngCatSANWXLAEw0_OPA4xGmlb6PN0qHphQ24npwsqqswcxA0i6mAhSU1huxwSU2VIn0BcbZd4oX1j6DsMQIRxxoaQ8mhhF3xfNkIeACPgly6Bc7uXFTZE9f0M6UxaUgrivdcXLX8LtCFpGRJms0voZaRolVvmgegHwclAMBsBS0TN56FldE9QXXGS4k4LJprwjXTpxrE2eEeum-CQpiljvXkuotONASek-62a-YKWhhoYukxIcud3_hq45KJP3AzW6wLx7IMx2HBnPMaUmXJl4-7nR7r_NPSeJsffLa62MQ4HI84qNR0ToMQpqilSJCYaGo37VbYy9UekA0WSRoYSmiZ0CMXTBo9tW1VVkST5kZAZ9h2RZl_-W-agfkxzT7cZxaoKAc1pP1G380w2T5Zl8TGwYLqVbPWMf-Iyih9hrQ7oitv7xQqVuCNI4Q_hq1D0kjMrEetMaDP8mNKoAosJ1_b8hUlYXj5geAL9alkcarwQchn4cXwXfLvOxEWjthHAuUPavdwgEGznuTRfT94dpUdz2s9vx9_ajguS07gOz1dOM5RR65yVUXZoH7mTkYqzzj5EHjCbzi-7m7WpgY2cGt5amj-XMnmVQqjjLCto1anKeuhnY_ummurWWCO_zjJmdhMfuMvN785KLdZjABmR0QzXg9-aOoJheK4kne-rJl4xpX0IcDFwHxzQTWoFYVltPJfY2YUDQfSOVtSrbIEU4VHP7ewCB6NTsP2ZU2sJRHSXpcppLDmwKMeEbFSyiB-VbXMiE_a_VU8jF1cl6BkBGor4PunGKCWfeuIXywqqWZ9sYQnRnXRXA-_9d1EQv7yC-LKgVbViSJJviLrrSgpf8ZHi4-6mGUdE2M4FyilLNMq8pkI825RRYPr8dWtdLavuECwYxV9qrzcOfkUuNIQ-SFXkmd6JNQ9jDw5VLshPwTrnHfXubqbIUfAoEwEiBWs0rFZz_Q7aV_WsBllUg4rSeiujFgmOdWWewXo_L3myd9Q9eoUMtWiTa3I-ElmyfhOdcn8Oiznj3094lzLojCLEsvlp7mC8FtJe84qYDKlA",
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCJ9.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.f9x2VPo2-1lNb7PNlcPqRXe4A78m546Y557nAjSoBYRDrwwQj6r3uYG6zzkOXFOhXnbCDchTaFv0kn8cDKNFaQWKaw_XIGYveihof9h9bX8lj7V72L1hWlya2zriMFhATeePmL4VUMu9khg3yD1Z-Sj0RM4IP0rPzbYN3IskuAN5lNXeTdV0xrra9FdvMolrRdMT9Bt14-QG8za4OoWDTb-s5Bq8kZUrhiVkKP4GowRYWBLFXxKThrPE4zQK6EJREMbmBTHy3nrxF_smNqQjCwE95T0qBAnPC6hQQEXO_U_J3EcAD9hPB-bzFiR3nIs6rK_MEinwcSs6QEgl4CDOxw"
}
```

To Send message to a channel

Delegated permissions required to send message: "ChannelMessage.Send Group.ReadWrite.All"

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/team_ID/channels/channel_ID/messages' --header 'Authorization:  Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IloxNG9xVEI5cjFYcldGZUJQQzNjU0VwR2p3aXlpUUZPVC1hTXBsaTZrMFkiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCIsImtpZCI6ImtnMkxZczJUMENUaklmajRydDZKSXluZW4zOCJ9.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.SDn4NIiHLxvGp0odn7C_hXZ0juSsgnyE_Dc0uTwMK_jP_n7-SjisYfw1vOoX7st5-C27_HwLoSWxUt1cqL7ENcrt_7HXvZSwFsXVN4JCeEOVZUZUzUakcmttUISPPPygLhv4-EPD-sBC8TDs9ncIYDUKqbTYh1aKkRsIK5O19GvoJQ4UUzHV6o-raW8jTBdXRfH1Bz6N7CPfcPkivTn1a-zOthy1HrlFBCFCErJBum_3QhmAHkoA9UPOEKKZeJBl_k3VqsZBcNById-X591ukyi06Kk8kHfYoigiiXm7lv0-NLsHoVq9e4sBemIjYzHd3mUhN3ayPYOTAwnUCsb9kA' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '
{
  "body": {
    "content": "Hello world"
  }
}'
```

Below will be the response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#teams('<team-ID>')/channels('<channel_ID>')/messages/$entity",
    "id": "1605635994172",
    "replyToId": null,
    "etag": "1605635994172",
    "messageType": "message",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-11-17T17:59:54.172Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-11-17T17:59:54.172Z",
    "lastEditedDateTime": null,
    "deletedDateTime": null,
    "subject": null,
    "summary": null,
    "chatId": null,
    "importance": "normal",
    "locale": "en-us",
    "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/message/channel-ID/1605635994172?groupId=<team-ID>&tenantId=<tenant-ID>&createdTime=1605635994172&parentMessageId=1605635994172",
    "policyViolation": null,
    "from": {
        "application": null,
        "device": null,
        "conversation": null,
        "user": {
            "id": "4faab178-9f24-4cd7-a144-d261c91d1ba2",
            "displayName": "admin",
            "userIdentityType": "aadUser"
        }
    },
    "body": {
        "contentType": "text",
        "content": "Hello World"
    },
    "channelIdentity": {
        "teamId": "team-ID",
        "channelId": "channel-ID"
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "mentions": [],
    "reactions": []
}
```